# What is the proper way to manipulate mutual content among RecyclerViews with Android Architecture Components

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I've got an `Activity` with 2 `Fragment`s sharing mutual items. When I bookmark an item from one `Fragment`, I would like to see it bookmarked on the other `Fragment`.

When I `@Delete` an item from one of the fragments, it is also deleted in the other fragment, however, when I `@Update` the item, it does not even update in current fragment.

Both fragments are using same `ViewModel` through their common parent `Activity`.

What is the proper way to achieve this would be?

#### Dao

```
@Dao
interface RssDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insertArticles(rssItem: List<Article>)

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun updateArticle(article: Article)

@Delete
fun deleteArticle(article: Article)
```

#### Repository

```
private fun getRssFeed(url: String): LiveData<Resource<List<Article>>> {
    return object : NetworkBoundResource<List<Article>, ArrayList<Article>>(appContext) {

        override fun loadFromDb(): LiveData<List<Article>> = rssDao.getAllRss()

        override fun createCall(): LiveData<ApiResponse<ArrayList<Article>>> =
                rssFeedProvider.fetch(url)

        override fun saveCallResult(item: ArrayList<Article>) {
            rssDao.insertArticles(item)
        }

        override fun shouldFetch(data: List<Article>?): Boolean {
           ...
        }

        override fun onFetchFailed() {
            DebugUtils.log("onFetchFailed")
        }

        override fun processResponse(response: ApiResponse<ArrayList<Article>>):
                ArrayList<Article>? = response.body

    }.asLiveData()
}

  fun updateArticle(article: Article) {
    bg {
        rssDao.updateArticle(article)
    }
}

fun deleteArticle(article: Article) {
    bg {
        rssDao.deleteArticle(article)
    }
}
```

#### ViewModel

```
private var rssResponses = rssRepo.getAllRss()

var rssUiModelData: LiveData<List<ArticleUiModel>> =
        Transformations.switchMap(rssResponses, { response ->   
            handleResponseData(response)
        })

private fun handleResponseData(response: Resource<List<Article>>): MutableLiveData<List<ArticleUiModel>> {

    response.data?.let {
        val sortedList = it.sortedWith(compareByDescending(Article::pubDateTimestamp))

        result.postValue(sortedList.map { article ->
            ArticleUiModel(article, newsClickCallback)
        })
    }

    return result
} 


/* when this function is called bookmark button onClick. The item is
    updated in the database but the LiveData from rssRepo.getAllRss() 
    is not updating the changes. On the other hand, If 
    rssRepo.deleteArticle(article)
    is called, it reacts to it and observer onChanged is called,
    hence adapter removes the item. */
 private fun toggleBookmark(article: Article) {
        if (article.bookmarked == 1) {
            article.bookmarked = 0
        } else {
            article.bookmarked = 1
        }

        rssRepo.updateArticle(article)
    }
```

#### Fragment

```
...
 viewModel = activity?.let { it ->
                    ViewModelProviders.of(it, factory)
                            .get(FeedViewModel::class.java)

 viewModel?.rssUiModelData?.observe(this, Observer {
                        adapter.addUiModels(it as Collection<BaseUiModelAlias>)})
...
```

Comment: Post your code so that we can see some hints.

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/#5
This may help

Comment: The requirements are pretty clear But To update items, you should notify your adapter recycler view will take care to update it self. If this is not working pls share your code.

Comment: Added related code to my question. There is no issue with adapter updating itself. The `onChanged` method s not triggered for the `LiveData` returned from `@Dao` after `@Update` is done. When I `@Delete` an item, adapter updates and removes item too but when I `@Update`, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an adapter for your Recyclerview and running the class function `notifyDataSetChanged` will refresh your recyclerview whether it's deleted or updated.

```
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(your_adapter);
your_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Look into this site if you do not have set an adapter for each viewholder of recyclerview: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jisu. There is no issue with adapter updating itself. The onChanged is not triggered for the LiveData returned from Dao after `@Update` is done. When I `@Delete` an item, adapter updates and removes item too but when I `@Update`, nothing happens.